# Z bar (vinyl to carpet) gap between vinyl and bar

Tags: carpet, vinyl-flooring, threshold

I have to fit z bar between click vinyl and carpet. There is a 3mm gap between the zbar and the vinyl.

I have tried trying to bend the zbar down but it won’t budge.[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you installing it the right way around? Shouldn't the 'upper' part of the Z-bar be over the carpet and not over the vinyl?

Comment: I don’t think so. There is only gripper on the one side (lower side), so the carpet must go that side?

Comment: I've never used Z-bar myself, but it seems that there are many different styles - some are adjustable to accommodate different heights of flooring material, while others are fixed. It looks like maybe the one you have is intended for use to transition to something a lot thicker than vinyl.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you got the carpet to tile which is higher than carpet to vinyl.

It might be too late to remove it from the carpet.

- But you can remove it by wedging it up and using an open angle grinder with a cutting wheel and carefully just cut the Z and remove it .
- Then adhere it with subfloor adhesive , polyurethane taking care not to cut anything else. Press tight with a board and some heavy stone weights.
- expose the edge so you can ensure it is tight.
- Leave it for at least a day to harden and 3 days to cure.